# Column 'AtivoCirculanteTotal' cannot be null

Tags: mysql, pdo, post

Estou achando muito estranho o que está ocorrendo porque ontem funcionou perfeitamente!

Criei o seguinte código:

```
require_once 'credenciais.php';

//pega dados do formulário de ativo e passivo circulante
$ac = isset($_POST['ac']) ? $_POST['ac'] : null;
$ae = isset($_POST['ae'])?$_POST['ae']:null;
$ad = isset($_POST['ad'])?$_POST['ad']:null;
$aco = isset($_POST['aco'])?$_POST['aco']:null;
$cr = isset($_POST['cr'])?$_POST['cr']:null;
$ncr11 = isset($_POST['ncr11'])?$_POST['ncr11']:null;
$ncr22 = isset($_POST['ncr22'])?$_POST['ncr22']:null;
$ncr33 = isset($_POST['ncr33'])?$_POST['ncr33']:null;
$ncr44 = isset($_POST['ncr44'])?$_POST['ncr44']:null;
$ncr55 = isset($_POST['ncr55'])?$_POST['ncr55']:null;
$est = isset($_POST['est'])?$_POST['est']:null;
$af = isset($_POST['af'])?$_POST['af']:null;
$da = isset($_POST['da'])?$_POST['da']:null;
$outc = isset($_POST['outc'])?$_POST['outc']:null;
$pc = isset($_POST['pc'])?$_POST['pc']:null;
$pee = isset($_POST['pee'])?$_POST['pee']:null;
$pef = isset($_POST['pef'])?$_POST['pef']:null;
$pco = isset($_POST['pco'])?$_POST['pco']:null;
$nfor = isset($_POST['nfor'])?$_POST['nfor']:null;
$for11 = isset($_POST['for11'])?$_POST['for11']:null;
$for22 = isset($_POST['for22'])?$_POST['for22']:null;
$for33 = isset($_POST['for33'])?$_POST['for33']:null;
$for44 = isset($_POST['for44'])?$_POST['for44']:null;
$for55 = isset($_POST['for55'])?$_POST['for55']:null;
$sal = isset($_POST['sal'])?$_POST['sal']:null;
$imp = isset($_POST['imp'])?$_POST['imp']:null;
$de = isset($_POST['de'])?$_POST['de']:null;
$adc = isset($_POST['adc'])?$_POST['adc']:null;


//insere banco na tabela de ativo e passivo circulante

$PDO = db_connect();
$sql_insere_ativopassivocirculante = "INSERT INTO ativopassivocirculante 
(AtivoCirculanteTotal, AtivoErratico, AtivoDisponiveis, 
AtivoCirculanteOperacionalTotal,    AtivoCRTotal, 
AtivoCRate30,AtivoCRde31a60, AtivoCRde61a90, AtivoCRacima90, 
AtivoCRInadimplentes, AtivoEstoque, AtivoAdiantForne, AtivoDespAnt, 
AtivoOutrosCirculantes, PassivoCirculanteTotal, PassivoEmprestimos, 
PassivoFinanciamentos, PassivoCirculanteOperacionalTotal, FornecedoresTotal,  
PassivoForate30, PassivoForde31a60, PassivoForde61a90, PassivoForacima90,  
PassivoForatrasados,  PassivoSalarios, PassivoImpostos, PassivoEstrutura , 
PassivoAdiantClientes, DataInclusao) VALUES (:ac, :ae, :ad, :aco, :cr, 
:ncr11, :ncr22, :ncr33, :ncr44, :ncr55, :est, :af, :da, :outc, :pc, :pee, 
:pef, :pco, :nfor, :for11, :for22, :for33, :for44, :for55, :sal, :imp, :de, 
:adc, CURRENT_DATE)";

 $insert_ativopassivocirculante = $PDO 
 >prepare($sql_insere_ativopassivocirculante);
 $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':ac',$ac );
 $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':ae',$ae );
 $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':ad',$ad );
 $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':aco',$aco );
 $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':cr',$cr );
 $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':ncr11',$ncr11 );
 $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':ncr22',$ncr22 );
 $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':ncr33',$ncr33 );
 $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':ncr44',$ncr44 );
 $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':ncr55',$ncr55 );
 $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':est',$est );
 $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':af',$af );
 $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':da',$da );
 $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':outc',$outc );
 $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':pc',$pc );
 $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':pee',$pee );
 $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':pef',$pef );
 $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':pco',$pco );
 $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':nfor',$nfor );
 $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':for11',$for11 );
 $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':for22',$for22 );
 $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':for33',$for33 );
 $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':for44',$for44 );
 $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':for55',$for55 );
 $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':sal',$sal );
 $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':imp',$imp );
 $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':de',$de );
 $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':adc',$adc );

 if($insert_ativopassivocirculante->execute()){
     header('Location: index.html');
 }else{
     echo "erro ao cadastrar";
     print_r($insert_ativopassivocirculante->errorInfo());
}
```

A mensagem de erro que deu foi:

> erro ao cadastrarArray ( [0] => 23000 [1] => 1048 [2] => Column
>   'AtivoCirculanteTotal' cannot be null )

Quando eu substituo  valor de null para 0 (por exemplo) em:

```
$ac = isset($_POST['ac']) ? $_POST['ac'] : null;
```

ele grava o valor "o" na tabela. Ou seja, parece que não está "pegando" o `$_POST`

Alguma luz?

O HTML está assim:

```html
<form method="POST" action="inserir.php" >
    <div id="circulantes">
        <div class="ativocirculante" id="ativocirculante">
            <h2>ATIVO CIRCULANTE<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="ac" name="ac" class="ValoresItensTOT" readonly/></h2>
            <h2>Ativo Errático (Financeiro) <input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00 aplicações" id="ae" name="ae" class="ValoresItens" /></h2>
            <h2>Disponíveis<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="ad" name="ad" class="ValoresItens" /></h2>
            <h2>ACO<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="aco" name="aco" class="ValoresItensTOT" readonly /></h2>
            <h2>Contas a receber<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="cr" name="cr" class="ValoresItensTOT" readonly /></h2>
            <h2 id="cr1">Até 30 dias<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="cr11"  name="ncr11" class="ValoresItens" /></h2>
            <h2 id="cr2">31 a 60 dias<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="cr22" name="ncr22" class="ValoresItens"/></h2>
            <h2 id="cr3">61 a 90 dias<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="cr33" name="ncr33" class="ValoresItens" /></h2>
            <h2 id="cr4">Acima de 90 dias<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="cr44" name="ncr44" class="ValoresItens" /></h2>
            <h2 id="cr5">(-) Inadimplentes<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="cr55" name="ncr55" class="ValoresItens" /></h2>
            <h2>Estoque<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="est" name="est" class="ValoresItens" /></h2>
            <h2>Adiant. a Fornecedores<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="af" name="af" class="ValoresItens"  /></h2>
            <h2>Despesas antecipadas<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="da" name="da" class="ValoresItens"  /></h2>
            <h2>Outros Circulantes<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="outc" name="outc" class="ValoresItens"  /></h2>

        </div>

        <div class="passivocirculante" id="passivocirculante">
            <h2>PASSIVO CIRCULANTE<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="pc" name="pc" class="ValoresItensTOT" readonly/></h2>
            <h2>Passivo Empréstimos<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00 empréstimos" id="pee" name="pee" class="ValoresItens" /></h2>
            <h2>Passivo Financiamentos<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00 financiamentos" id="pef" name="pef" class="ValoresItens"/></h2>
            <h2>PCO<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="pco" name="pco" class="ValoresItensTOT" readonly/></h2>
            <h2>Fornecedores a pagar<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="for" name="nfor" class="ValoresItensTOT" readonly/></h2>
            <h2 id="for1">Até 30 dias<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="for11" name="for11" class="ValoresItens"/></h2>
            <h2 id="for2">31 a 60 dias<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="for22" name="for22" class="ValoresItens"/></h2>
            <h2 id="for3">61 a 90 dias<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="for33" name="for33" class="ValoresItens"/></h2>
            <h2 id="for4">Acima de 90 dias<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="for44" name="for44" class="ValoresItens"/></h2>
            <h2 id="cr5">(+) Atrasados<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="for55" name="for55" class="ValoresItens" /></h2>
            <h2>Salários a pagar<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="sal" name="sal" class="ValoresItens"/></h2>
            <h2>Impostos a pagar<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="imp" name="imp" class="ValoresItens"/></h2>
            <h2>Despesas com estrutura<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="de" name="de" class="ValoresItens"/></h2>
            <h2>Adiantamento de clientes<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="adc" name="adc" class="ValoresItens"/></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Salvar" class="btn btn-success" />
</form>
<div class="resp"></div>
<div class="ok"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Coloque um `var_dump($_POST); exit;` antes de tudo e coloca aqui o resultado

Comment: Certo. O resultado foi:`array(0) { }`

Answer (score 2):

A mensagem está falando que a coluna `AtivoCirculanteTotal` não pode ser nula, ou seja, o campo foi criado com `NOT NULL`. O que muito provavelmente esta ocorrendo é que não esta sendo passado via `POST` o valor de `ac`, ou seja, a variável `$_POST['ac']` não esta setada.

Na linha 4 o programa verifica se a variável `$_POST['ac']` esta setada. Se não estiver, atribui `null` na variável `$ac`, esse `null` é passado via parâmetro para o `PDO`.

Resumindo, o programa está tentando inserir `null` em um campo que não pode ser nulo.

O que você pode fazer, é somente continuar a execução se a variável `$_POST['ac']` estiver setada:

```
require_once 'credenciais.php';

//pega dados do formulário de ativo e passivo circulante
if (isset($_POST['ac'])) {
    $ac = $_POST['ac'];
    $ae = isset($_POST['ae'])?$_POST['ae']:null;
    $ad = isset($_POST['ad'])?$_POST['ad']:null;
    $aco = isset($_POST['aco'])?$_POST['aco']:null;
    $cr = isset($_POST['cr'])?$_POST['cr']:null;
    $ncr11 = isset($_POST['ncr11'])?$_POST['ncr11']:null;
    $ncr22 = isset($_POST['ncr22'])?$_POST['ncr22']:null;
    $ncr33 = isset($_POST['ncr33'])?$_POST['ncr33']:null;
    $ncr44 = isset($_POST['ncr44'])?$_POST['ncr44']:null;
    $ncr55 = isset($_POST['ncr55'])?$_POST['ncr55']:null;
    $est = isset($_POST['est'])?$_POST['est']:null;
    $af = isset($_POST['af'])?$_POST['af']:null;
    $da = isset($_POST['da'])?$_POST['da']:null;
    $outc = isset($_POST['outc'])?$_POST['outc']:null;
    $pc = isset($_POST['pc'])?$_POST['pc']:null;
    $pee = isset($_POST['pee'])?$_POST['pee']:null;
    $pef = isset($_POST['pef'])?$_POST['pef']:null;
    $pco = isset($_POST['pco'])?$_POST['pco']:null;
    $nfor = isset($_POST['nfor'])?$_POST['nfor']:null;
    $for11 = isset($_POST['for11'])?$_POST['for11']:null;
    $for22 = isset($_POST['for22'])?$_POST['for22']:null;
    $for33 = isset($_POST['for33'])?$_POST['for33']:null;
    $for44 = isset($_POST['for44'])?$_POST['for44']:null;
    $for55 = isset($_POST['for55'])?$_POST['for55']:null;
    $sal = isset($_POST['sal'])?$_POST['sal']:null;
    $imp = isset($_POST['imp'])?$_POST['imp']:null;
    $de = isset($_POST['de'])?$_POST['de']:null;
    $adc = isset($_POST['adc'])?$_POST['adc']:null;


    //insere banco na tabela de ativo e passivo circulante

    $PDO = db_connect();
    $sql_insere_ativopassivocirculante = "INSERT INTO ativopassivocirculante (AtivoCirculanteTotal, AtivoErratico, AtivoDisponiveis, 
AtivoCirculanteOperacionalTotal,    AtivoCRTotal, 
AtivoCRate30,AtivoCRde31a60, AtivoCRde61a90, AtivoCRacima90, 
AtivoCRInadimplentes, AtivoEstoque, AtivoAdiantForne, AtivoDespAnt, 
AtivoOutrosCirculantes, PassivoCirculanteTotal, PassivoEmprestimos, 
PassivoFinanciamentos, PassivoCirculanteOperacionalTotal, FornecedoresTotal,  
PassivoForate30, PassivoForde31a60, PassivoForde61a90, PassivoForacima90,  
PassivoForatrasados,  PassivoSalarios, PassivoImpostos, PassivoEstrutura , 
PassivoAdiantClientes, DataInclusao) VALUES (:ac, :ae, :ad, :aco, :cr, 
:ncr11, :ncr22, :ncr33, :ncr44, :ncr55, :est, :af, :da, :outc, :pc, :pee, 
:pef, :pco, :nfor, :for11, :for22, :for33, :for44, :for55, :sal, :imp, :de, 
:adc, CURRENT_DATE)";

    $insert_ativopassivocirculante = $PDO->prepare($sql_insere_ativopassivocirculante);
    $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':ac',$ac );
    $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':ae',$ae );
    $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':ad',$ad );
    $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':aco',$aco );
    $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':cr',$cr );
    $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':ncr11',$ncr11 );
    $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':ncr22',$ncr22 );
    $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':ncr33',$ncr33 );
    $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':ncr44',$ncr44 );
    $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':ncr55',$ncr55 );
    $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':est',$est );
    $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':af',$af );
    $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':da',$da );
    $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':outc',$outc );
    $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':pc',$pc );
    $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':pee',$pee );
    $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':pef',$pef );
    $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':pco',$pco );
    $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':nfor',$nfor );
    $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':for11',$for11 );
    $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':for22',$for22 );
    $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':for33',$for33 );
    $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':for44',$for44 );
    $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':for55',$for55 );
    $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':sal',$sal );
    $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':imp',$imp );
    $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':de',$de );
    $insert_ativopassivocirculante-> bindParam(':adc',$adc );

    if($insert_ativopassivocirculante->execute()){
        header('Location: index.html');
    }else{
        echo "erro ao cadastrar";
        print_r($insert_ativopassivocirculante->errorInfo());
    }
} else {
    echo "Não foi passado o ac";
}
```

Comment: Oi Roberto, obrigado pela sugestão,mas acredito que não funcionou.
Não retornou dados para o MYSQL e também, quando forçamos passar pela variável $ac ele diz que a próxima ($ae) não pode ser nula.

Comment: Então você não pode passar `null` para esses campos. Como você esta enviando os parâmetros para o `PHP`?

Comment: O que é estranho é que estava funcionando perfeitamente ontem, alguma coisa aconteceu que deixou de funcionar. Acredito que o problema esteja sim em setar a variável `$_POST` pra todas as variáveis. Estranho

Comment: coloca seu `HTML` na pergunta também.

Comment: Feito! Adicionei o HTML

Answer (score 0):

obrigado pela ajuda mas consegui achar a resposta. Meu servidor XAMPP, por algum razão, não estava conectando o MySQL. Reinstalei o software e o código voltou a funcionar perfeitamente.

Valeu :-)

Answer (score 0):

Descobri que era apenas um "espaço" aqui: 'nome_cidade '

```
$nome_cidade = isset($_POST['nome_cidade ']) ? $_POST['nome_cidade '] : null;
```